# Curl of an integral of a vector field?

Tags: integration, vectors, vector-analysis

I need some help with the integral

\begin{align}
\vec{\nabla }\times \left[ \frac{1}{4\pi\varepsilon } \int \frac{\rho \big( \hspace{0.375ex}\vec{r}\hspace{0.25ex}' \hspace{0.01ex}\big)}{\big\| \hspace{0.375ex}\vec{\eta}\hspace{0.1ex}^{2}\hspace{0.125ex} \big \|}\;\vec{\eta}\,dv\right ]
\end{align}

where 
$\;\vec{\eta}=\vec{r}-\vec{r}\hspace{0.1ex}'$.

This entire thing looks like a mess. Some help would be ideal.

Comment: I am assuming that you're doing electromagnetism, in which case your integral is an $\mathbf{E}$ sourced by a density $\rho$. In any case, you'll want to apply Faraday's law to find the curl of an electric field.

Comment: A physics answer: The integral gives the electric field produced by the volume charge density $\rho(\vec{r})$. But the curl of an electric field vanishes in the absence of a time-varying magnetic field (Faraday's law). So this integral should vanish. (Obviously, this only tells you what the answer _ought_ to be, not how to show it!)

Comment: @Semiclassical The book wants a brute force method by direct computation.

Comment: @EuYu brute force method without faraday's law